# Making lists, looping a function through a list and controlling output names

Tags: arcpy, feature-class, mxd

How do you output a list of multiple featurelayers from an mxd while controlling the output names of the shapefiles and overwriting the contents of the shapefile outputs if the the file already exists? Currently I'm using both the `FeatureClasstoFeatureClass_conversion()` and `CopyFeatures_management()` functions. I can get one featurelayer to output and overwrite a shapefile in a different location. But how to do this for a list of shapefiles?

```
import arcpy 
Mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")  
arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(Mxd)
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True  

sampleinputList = ["input_a", "input_b", "input_c"] #list of feature layers
sampleout_path = "T:/path" #output path 
samplenames = ["input_a_name", "input_b_name", "input_c_name"]
sampleOutputnamesList = ["T:/path/input_a_name", "T:/path/input_b_name", "T:/path/input_c_name"] # each input corresponds to a respective output name
for featureclasses in sampleinputList:
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(sampleinputList,sampleOutputnamesList)
    #neither of these list structures worked :/    
for featureclasses in sampleinputList:
    arcpy.FeatureClasstoFeatureClass_conversion(sampleinputList,sampleout_path,samplenames)
```

both instances give me a
    `Runtime error 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py",    line 2281, in CopyFeatures
    raise e
    RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool`

## Here's the part of the code I think should be amended:

```
#Filename mapping Dictionary
fileNames = {
'unique layer namea' : 'unique_shapefile_renamedA',
'unique layer nameb' : 'unique_shapefile_renamedB',
'unique layer nameC' : 'unique_shapefile_renamedC',
}

outPath = "T:\\path" #path to folder where new shapefiles will be output

for featureclass in listLayers: #this loops through the arcpy function seen on last line
    if featureclass.name.lower() in fileNames:
        outputName = '{}.shp'.format(fileNames[featureclass.name.lower()]) 
        outputPath = os.path.join(outPath, outputName)
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(featureclass, outputPath)
```

if the original syntax of the Copy Features management function is 
    `CopyFeatures_management (in_features, out_feature_class,)`
then shouldn't `featureclass` in last line of the block be defined in the way `outputPath` is defined?

Comment: Please confirm your indentation after the `if featureclass.name.lower()` line, as currently it's incorrect

Comment: Changed @Midavalo

Comment: 'shouldn't featureclass in last line of the block be defined in the way outputPath is defined?' - no, it is defined by `for featureclass in listLayers:`.  `featureclass` here is your `in_features` that you're copying to your `outputPath`.

Comment: @Midavalo well in that case it didn't do anything. There were no errors but none of the shapefiles seemed to be updated/exported based on the dates I see.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a list of your layers, and then loop through them, outputting them to your desired location.  You currently are getting your layer list, but not storing that list in a parameter.

Below I've modified your script to loop through the layers and output them to a folder, giving each layer a new (or slightly modified) name.  I've used both methods you've tried - you need to choose which on you prefer and remove the other.

```
import arcpy, os

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True  

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") 
layerList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd) # list of layers in MXD
outPath = r"D:\temp\SE\OutputFolder" #output path 

# Try this
for featureclass in layerList: # Using Copy Features
    outputName = '{}_cf_output.shp'.format(featureclass.name) # Creates a new output name
    outputPath = os.path.join(outPath, outputName)
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(featureclass, outputPath)

# Or try this
for featureclass in layerList: # Using Feature Class to Feature Class
    outputName = '{}_fc2fc_output.shp'.format(featureclass.name) # Creates a new output name
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(featureclass, outPath, outputName)
```

---

If you are wanting to completely rename each feature class name when you copy it (as per your comment), you will need to have a dictionary of old and new file names defined, rather than just outputting each layer it finds in the MXD.  Doing it this way will miss any layers that you haven't defined in the dictionary.

```
import arcpy, os

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True  

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") 
layerList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd) # list of layers in MXD

# Dictionary of filename mapping
# {Old Filename: New Filename}
fileNames = {
             'input_a': 'input_a_name',
             'input_b': 'input_b_name',
             'input_c': 'input_c_name'
            }

outPath = r"D:\temp\SE\OutputFolder" #output path 

for featureclass in layerList: # Using Copy Features
    if featureclass.name.lower() in fileNames:
        outputName = '{}.shp'.format(fileNames[featureclass.name]) # Creates a new output name
        outputPath = os.path.join(outPath, outputName)
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(featureclass, outputPath)
```

The dictionary is set up with the old name (the layer name in your MXD), and the name you want it called once output to shapefile.  Arcpy will loop through the layers in your MXD, and if they're listed in the dictionary it will copy the layer out to a shapefile using the new name in the dictionary.

Put your older filename/layer name in the dictionary in lowercase so that python can do a match by comparing the lowercase layer name (`featureclass.name.lower()`) - remember that Python is very case specific!

Comment: Hey @Midavalo, Thanks for this. How exactly does the `outputName` allow me  to specify the name I'd like the output shapefiles to take on? I wouldn't want to try it without knowing how I can specify what each of the layers will be renamed to. Btw I chose to go with the `CopyFeatures_management`option because the `FeatureClass_conversion` doesn't duplicate all of the files that are made up within the shapefile. It outputs only 4 as opposed to 6 for some reason eg the .prj . shx etc

Comment: @SteeleJohnson the line `outputName = '{}_cf_output.shp'.format(featureclass.name) ` is what gives your output a new filename.  If your input feature class is `Abcde` it will name your output `Abcde_cf_output.shp`.  The `{}` is a placeholder in the string for the `featureclass.name` passed to it using the `.format()`, and the rest of the string `_cf_output.shp` is added to the end.

Comment: @SteeleJohnson you can of course change this to whatever you want the new output to be.  The `featureclass.name` comes from the input feature class, and this helps ensure each output has a unique name.

Comment: I see. What if I already had set names for output files. For example a layer in a map named `Verybigpark` gets exported and renamed as something along the lines of `vbPark` and overwrites an existing shapefile called `vbPark` whereas a layer called `TinyRiver` gets called `TnyRiv`? Where each output name is different. Is that possible?

Comment: @SteeleJohnson I have added extra code for if you want to pre-map your layers to new filenames.  If you don't want to pre-map them, you can use the first code I gave, as that will output each layer with a different name based on the existing layer name plus any extra text you want to add.

Comment: I think this is pretty close although I'm thinking that maybe in the last line `featureclass`  should not be in place of the input_features. I say this because after running it, nothing changed. There were no errors but the function didn't produce any results (as I can see when looking at the dates).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44119/discussion-between-steelejohnson-and-midavalo).

Comment: @SteeleJohnson instead of adding lots of comments, edit your Question and add your code as you have it now.  I don't know where your `input_features` is coming from as I don't have that in my code and it's not in your original either.

Comment: it has been updated